# window.postMessage internet explorer 11 support

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, postmessage

I am attempting to use `postMessage()` to send data to a new window that is spawned from a parent window. `postMessage()` works fine in chrome/firefox but with internet explorer it seems to be choking on my `addEventListener` and no data is being sent to the new page.

I understand that for IE you should use `attachEvent` which I have implemented, but the child page supports `addEventListener`, just the parent page does not while referencing the child.

Parent:

```
var newTab = window.open('community_PrinterFriendlyEligibility');
if (newTab.addEventListener) {
     console.log('add1');
     newTab.addEventListener('load', function() {
         console.log('add2');
         newTab.postMessage(data,'*');
     });

 } else if (newTab.attachEvent) {
     console.log('attach1');
     newTab.attachEvent('load', function() {
         console.log('attach2');
         newTab.postMessage(data,'*');
     });
 }
```

Child:

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
    console.log('add');
    window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
         //process chrome
    }, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    console.log('attach');
    window.attachEvent('message', function(event) {
         //process IE
     });
 }
```

> Debug in IE:
>
> ```
> Parent Window:
>     attach1
>
> child Window:
>     add
> ```
>
> Debug in Chrome:
>
> ```
> Parent Window:
>     add1
>     add2
>
> child Window:
>     add
> ```

So in IE, the parent reference to the child window does not have `addEventListener` but the child window accepts `addEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

Afaik it's not needed in IE11: http://caniuse.com/#search=addEventListener

Just tested this in IE11 and can confirm it uses addEventlistener.

Are you emulating IE8 in the parent page? This would use attach.

The new window would revert back to default (Edge), which would use add.

Comment: spawning the child window only allows me to use attachEvent. addEventListener works while im on the child page though. I am not using an emulator

Comment: Did some testing via the console. IE11.0.9600.17501 - Edge modus: window.addEventlistener is a function, and window.attachEvent is undefined. In IE8 emulation it's the other way around. For newTab - it depends on modus set in the target window, which makes sense. Edge modus: addEventListener is a function, attachEvent undefined. IE8 emulation: addEventListener is undefined, attachEvent is an object.

Comment: One more question: are there any metatags in the page that force IE to use a legacy mode? See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: File>Properties menu in IE will tell you which IE security zone your test site is mapped to. Use the Emulation tab of the IE dev tool to find out how IE8 Emulation is being established... eg. Enterprise Mode - Enterprise Site Mode list, IE8 - intranet compatibility view.